# Template template for std::vector fails to build on icc16

Tags: c++11, templates

I have a class that has a container in it. This container must be a template and must accept std::vector. The code needs to be C++11 standard. I have simplified for this question, but it is equivalent to:

```
#include <vector>

template <template <typename, typename...> class Container>
class Test {
    Container<double> c;
};

class TestImplementation : public Test<std::vector> {};
```

Recently I have found this fails to build for icpc16 as shown by CompilerExplorer https://godbolt.org/g/AGgojV with the error message:

```
too few arguments for template template parameter "Container"
      Container<double> c;
```

It compiles for gcc, clang and icpc17. Is this a bug in icpc16 or is my code incorrect?

Comment: Sounds like "not 100% compliant yet"

Comment: Do you mean that the compiler is not compliant or my code is not?

Comment: The compiler isn't fully compliant, but is working towards it. As evidenced by the next version accepting it.